# Convert JWT token to ClaimsPrincipal without token expiry validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt, identityserver3

We have a scenario in our app where we have old JWT tokens that are expired. We just wanna to convert it ClaimsPrincipal without validating the token expiration. Currently, we have `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken` which validates the exp. We are using IdentityServer3 for generating JWT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, I was able to find the answer. I just need to set         `ValidateLifetime`,

```
    validationParameters.ValidateLifetime = False
```

Offcourse, this is never recommended to set it to false. But in our case we have a use case.